# Split string with regex not working

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to split big file with some regex. Problem is that I want to keep delimiter in text after split, and I tried to add ?= on the beggining of regex, but then it doesn't split. I tried modified regex in Sublime, and it's working there.

Text is like this:
Aug 07, 2014 01:01:01 PM
 
some text 
Aug 07, 2014 02:02:02 PM
So, date, then some text and date. I want to get split text with regex which recognize that date.

First version of regex, which works perfectlly for my purpose:

```
\w{3}\s\d{2}\,\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[AM|PM].)
```

Code in Python is this:

```
allparts = re.compile(r'\w{3}\s\d{2}\,\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[AM|PM].').split(alltext)
```

After adding ?=, it looks like this:

```
allparts2 =re.compile(r'(?=\w{3}\s\d{2}\,\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[AM|PM].)').split(alltext)
```

What I'm doing wrong in second code?

Comment: What about : (?=\w{3} \d{2}, \d{4}, [\d:]+ (?=AM|PM))

Comment: I can't find anything with that.

Comment: What does your allparts / allparts returns in each cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my first answer was wrong:) Try not adding ?=, only put it in parentheses like this:

```
allparts2 =re.compile(r'(\w{3}\s\d{2},\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[AM|PM].)').split(alltext)
```

Then try it without compile...

```
allparts2 = re.split('(\w{3}\s\d{2},\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[AM|PM].)', alltext)
```

When using:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import re

alltext = "Aug 07, 2014 01:01:01 PM some text Aug 07, 2014 02:02:02 PM another text Aug 07, 2014 03:03:03 AM " 

allparts2 = re.split('(?=\w{3}\s\d{2},\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[AM|PM].)', alltext)
print(allparts2)
```

Result was:

```
Executing the program....
$python2.7 main.py
['Aug 07, 2014 01:01:01 PM some text Aug 07, 2014 02:02:02 PM another text Aug 07, 2014 03:03:03 AM ']
```

When using:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import re

alltext = "Aug 07, 2014 01:01:01 PM some text Aug 07, 2014 02:02:02 PM another text Aug 07, 2014 03:03:03 AM "


allparts2 = re.split('(?:\w{3}\s\d{2},\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[AM|PM].)', alltext)

print(allparts2)
```

Result was:

```
Executing the program....
$python2.7 main.py
['', ' some text ', ' another text ', ' ']
```

When using:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import re

alltext = "Aug 07, 2014 01:01:01 PM some text Aug 07, 2014 02:02:02 PM another text Aug 07, 2014 03:03:03 AM "


allparts2 = re.split('(\w{3}\s\d{2},\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[AM|PM].)', alltext)

print(allparts2)
```

Result was:

```
Executing the program....
$python2.7 main.py
['', 'Aug 07, 2014 01:01:01 PM', ' some text ', 'Aug 07, 2014 02:02:02 PM', ' another text ', 'Aug 07, 2014 03:03:03 AM', ' ']
```

Just to compare different forms.

Comment: I don't where is the problem. I tried your code standalone, and it's working ok. But when I copy regex in my script, it doesn't work there. Can it be because my string is data from file? I opened file, and saved everything from read() method.

Comment: It would also help if you print out the string which contains the data from file, to see what exactly is in it.

Comment: It is just data = openFile.read(). But I solved my problem without this, and just simply wrote my own split method. But your method worked on another file so I will use that regex there. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that python's re.split() doesn't split on zero-length matches.

However, the manual says

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.
>
> ...
>
> If there are capturing groups in the separator and it matches at the start of the string, the result will start with an empty string.

So you can use :

```
allparts2 = re.compile(r'(\w{3}\s\d{2}\,\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s(?:AM|PM))')
```

Where the matching expression is surrounded by a capturing group (also notice the un-capturing group at the end). The result is :

```
['', 'Aug 07, 2014 01:01:01 PM', ' some text ', 'Aug 07, 2014 02:02:02 PM', ' another text ', 'Aug 07, 2014 03:03:03 AM', ' ']
```

You can then create your files by grouping `allparts[1], allparts[2]` and so on (2n+1, 2n+2).

Comment: Sorry, I added by mistake ',' after year. It should be without ','

Comment: And still, this will find all lines, but in splitting, it will delete them.

Comment: Here is another shot at it. I removed the correction since it was just a typo. I still left the corrected alternation and remove the last `.`

Answer (score 0):

Although I am unfamiliar with the Python flavour, [Pythex](https://pythex.org) gives me the following, I assume correct, results :

See the [result](https://pythex.org/?regex=%28%3F%3A%5Cw%7B3%7D%20%5Cd%7B2%7D%2C%20%5Cd%7B4%7D%2C%20%5B%5Cd%3A%5D%2B%20%28AM%7CPM%29%29&test_string=Aug%2007%2C%202014%2C%2001%3A01%3A01%20PM%0Asome%20text%20%0AAug%2007%2C%202014%2C%2002%3A02%3A02%20PM&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Even if these are not, there are several things in your regex which are unnecessary and/or incorrect by my knowledge.

- A comma does not need to be escaped
- A conditional is not done by [ condo | cond2] , but rather by parentheses (cond1|cond2)
- The `\s` you have is optional as regex catches a white space, which is correct if you want to catch e.g. a space character, a tab character, a carriage return character, ..

Lastly, the item you are adding `?=` is a lookahead, ?: makes it match, but does not make it part of your capture group.

Try this regex : (?:\w{3} \d{2}, \d{4}, [\d:]+ (?:AM|PM))

Comment: Nothing. Still, the delimiter is missing after split.